# back press to switch from action bar navigation mode tabs to standard

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a list fragment, which contains a list of items. When I tap on some of the items, the navigation mode changes from NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS and two tabs will appear. I want the navigation mode to change back to standard (with both tabs removed) when I press on back button. However, I cannot find to place to put addToBackStack() and thus unable to implement this navigation. Could someone give me some suggestions?

Many thanks in advance